# Using Ogre library locally for a project

Tags: c++, macos, ogre

what I would like to do is to have an application (I am currently working off the sample framework app) and include any ogre library files with it, as opposed to have it installed for the whole system. This way I can easily port the application onto other computers once built.

I am on Mac OS 10.9. I built Ogre by first running the CMake app to configure the Xcode project, then opening the created Xcode project and building the Install and SampleBrowser congifurations. A directory sdk/lib was created in the Ogre directory. This contains directories debug, OGRE and pkgconfig. The OGRE directory has all the samples .dylib files. What I do not see is the main ogre library file.

The contents of the file lib/pkgconfig/Ogre.pc suggest that there should be a library file called OgreMain in the lib directory:

```
Libs: -L${libdir} -lOgreMain  -lpthread
```

As far as I understand it, I need this library file to be a part of my project. I could then link the sdk/include for all the Ogre's header files. I am confused about how to make this work. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this is Ogre 1.8. In that case the libraries and frameworks need to be installed in your application bundle. Inside MyApp.app/Contents you will need folders named Components, Plugins and Frameworks. Ogre.framework goes in frameworks, component dylibs go into Components, plugin dylibs go in Plugins.

Comment: Thanks for that! Just out of curiosity, does something similar happen on Windows, or does windows work with library files? Just wondering for future, when my application will also need a Windows version

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a great tutorial that worked straight away for me here: http://will.thimbleby.net/ogre3d-tutorial/

This is for Ogre 1.8, the only difference when using Ogre1.9 is that you don't use RenderSystem_GL.dylib but RenderSystem_GL.framework (found at the same place as Ogre.framework) and you deal with it in the same manner in terms of your project setup as with Ogre.framework.